# nested for each loop not working to append dictionaries to list in django

Tags: django

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries to model a django models.Model. The model is named voteTemp. This prints out each dictionary, voteTempRecordDict, as each is created in each iteration of the loop:

```
>>> voteTempRecordsList = []
>>> voteTempRecordDict = {}
>>> for each in VoteTemp.objects.all():
...     for each2 in each.__dict__:
...         if each2 is not '_state':
...             voteTempRecordDict.update({each2:each.__dict__[each2]})
...     print voteTempRecordDict
```

So I would think this would work to append each voteTempRecordDict to the voteTempRecordsList (to make a list of the dictionaries), but it just creates a list containing the last dictionary, repeated the number of times as there are objects in VoteTemp:

```
>>> voteTempRecordsList = []
>>> voteTempRecordDict = {}
>>> for each in VoteTemp.objects.all():
...     for each2 in each.__dict__:
...         if each2 is not '_state':
...             voteTempRecordDict.update({each2:each.__dict__[each2]})
...     voteTempRecordsList.append(voteTempRecordDict)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..
Untested code

```
 >>> voteTempRecordsList = []
 >>> for each in VoteTemp.objects.all():
            voteTempRecordDict = {}
    ...     for each2 in each.__dict__:
    ...         if each2 is not '_state':
    ...             voteTempRecordDict.update({each2:each.__dict__[each2]})
    ...     voteTempRecordsList.append(voteTempRecordDict)
```

Comment: Great...then, you can close the post by marking it answered :)

Comment: I had to google to find out how to do this. It really should be more apparent by just looking at the page (a button that says "choose answer" or something clearer and more obvious than a hollowed-out check mark, in my opinion - in case someone in charge may read this). Thanks for the help, though.